# Inserting large amount of rows from one table to another on different hosts

Tags: python, postgresql

I have two tables TABLE A and TABLE B. I'm trying to figure out the best way to do two things:

1. Select a large number of rows from TABLE A (in the millions)
2. And then make a query on TABLE B to check which rows don't exist there and then insert them.

The two solutions i'm thinking of are:

1. Store all the columns from table A in a temporary table and then join on table B to insert the rows but the two tables are on different connections
   OR
2. Iterate through the rows i select from table A in batches and make multiple queries to table B

Code for the two steps in Python using psycopg2 libary:

```
conn, cursor, engine = get_db_connection("table_a")
query = """
            SELECT *
            FROM table_a
        """
cursor.execute(query)
# Problem here is i need to make a new connection to table_b as it's on a different host and figure out how to insert all the rows i queried before
conn, cursor, engine = get_db_connection("table_b")
query = """
            INSERT INTO
            table_b
            VALUES
        """
cursor.execute(query)
```

Also codewise i'm not sure how i'm supposed to create a temporary table and reuse it in a new connection in Python.

Comment: You could measure it, it's your code and your system. And pretty simple

Comment: Can you set up a Foreign Data Wrapper between the two databases? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html